# bootstrap model popup not working properly in mac google chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'am having problem in displaying bootstrap model popup in my mac pc google chrome.It actually displays but it automatically hides itself to the background after 1 sec.
My google chrome version is 23.
    I have tried this in firefox and it is working

Thanks,
Mrudhul

Answer (score 1):

if you have `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.js` in your markup, you have to remove individual  `bootstrap-modal.js`file.